# how can we disable profile.php for subscriber in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to disable the profile.php(complete dashboard) for subscribers only. they only veiw the main website, they can't view the dashboard panel. We have also made some roles for subscriber using cpca plugin, due to this visitor can view some pages, which only can possible through login in website.

Please suggest me any plugins, or tips to complete this task,

Thanks

Alen

Answer (score 2):

I just had to figure this out... unfortunately, there aren't many great options in WordPress for disabling the profile page, so I had to use `wp_die()` on the page load action.

```
function disable_user_profile() {

    if ( is_admin() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( 2 == $user->ID )
            wp_die( 'You are not allowed to edit the user profile on this demo.' );

    }

}
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'disable_user_profile' );
```

In my example, I want to prevent a single user from editing their profile (it's for a demo site, blocking the demo admin user). But you could easily do a role or permission or anything else you want.

Answer (score 1):

with [members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) you can set user rights, so make a role and then don't give them any rights.
That should fix it. It will not disable the option to comment.